# Headers in Javascript and its use

Tags: javascript, json, axios, request-headers

I have just finished a task on updating the database written in JSON from the front end. 
I am still not clarified on the use of `headers` which is a type of `AxiosConfig`. What is the difference between using `axios` with it and without it.

For example:

What is the difference between

```
await axios.post(`${URL}/update`, JSON.stringify({urlSlug: apiHash}), 
    {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  ).data
```

And

```
await axios.post(`${URL}/update`, {apiHash})).data
```

I tried both and only the first one works in my case. But, after finishing the task, I still don't really know the difference in how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are part of the HTTP request structure. A request consists of many parts including URL, headers and body. Not everything is considered suitable to be specified in the body like api-keys, tokens, etc. These can be included in the header.

There are some details that the service running in the back-end needs in order to process a request. If the back-end service expects the request containing JSON data in the body to specify its type in header as JSON, it will not work if this isn't specified as there may be no handlers for non JSON type request in the back-end service.

You can read more about HTTP request structure here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the source. Really helpful!!